# Jquery Hide/show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just learning Jquery, I wanted to know if anyone can tell me what is wrong with my script. When a user hits submit on the form, I want 2 two div tags to open and the one containing the form to close.

Thanks!

This is the script

```
<script>
    $('#form_container').submit(function()
    {
        $('#form_container').hide()
        $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show()
    });
</script>
```

These are the div and form

```
<div id="mydivhide1" style="visibility:hidden">1111</div>
<div id="mydivhide2" style="visibility:hidden">2222</div>

<div id="form_container">
    <form id="form_710370"  method="post" convert.php">
        <input id="Website" name="url1" type="text" value=""/> 
        <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: is it coming inside your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Submit` your `form` not `div` like,

```
$('#form_710370').submit(function(){
   $('#form_container').hide()
   $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
   return false;
});
```

And `hide` your `div's` by using  `display:none` not by `visibility:hidden` like,

```
<div id="mydivhide1" style="display:none">1111</div>
<div id="mydivhide2" style="display:none">2222</div>
```

**Updated** if your `script` is `written` before your `DOM elements` then use `$(function(){...})` like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#form_710370').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); // add this
       $('#form_container').hide()
       $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
       return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree that it makes more sense to attach the submit handler to the form, but wouldn't it work on the div too? (jQuery makes it bubble even in IE.) I think the `visibility` thing is probably the real issue, assuming the script is running after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I have an additional question related to this. On the real page the form target actually posts to an Iframe, which take about 30 seconds to load, is there a way to have the hide/show events in this script delayed until the load is finished?

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$('#form_710370').submit(function()
{
$('#form_container').hide()
$('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show()
})
```

Comment: That won't work - what do you think will happen when the user clicks on one of the text input?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdJU9/1/

I've added CSS to hide the top divs, I think your inline style of visibility hidden was overriding the JS.

CSS

```
#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2{ display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydivhide1">1111</div>
<div id="mydivhide2">2222</div>
```

The fiddle throws an error for some reason but you get the idea ?

Comment: Thanks I am trying it now

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, please focus your syntax with semicolon at the end.

```
<script>

    $('#saveForm').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
       });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<script>
$('#form_710370').submit(function()
{
    $('#form_container').hide()
    $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show()
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in there:

```
<form id="form_710370"  method="post" convert.php">
```

should be

```
<form id="form_710370"  method="post" action="convert.php">
```

And for the JS:

```
 $('#form_710370').submit(function() {
     $('#form_container').hide();
     $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
 })
```

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/GZEmw/